# UIWebView throwing NSUnknownKeyException iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, uiwebview, uitabbar, nsexception

I have a tab bar application. Everything works normally, and I can switch between tabs fine and everything, except when I switch to my second tab `ProductViewClass` the view doesn't update and it spits out the console output below. I have nothing in this view except for a UIWebView and a UILabel. When I delete the UIWebView it runs successfully, and when I add another it still works. It only stops working when I connect the IBOutlet from my File's Owner to the UIWebView. Besides synthesizing and releasing `productWebView` the only non-template code in `ProductWebView.m` is this:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com/";
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [productWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    NSLog(@"Google loaded");
```

The entirety of ProductWebView.h is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ProductViewClass : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *productWebView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *productWebView;
@end
```

Here's the console output:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 52523.
2011-01-30 19:18:28.907 FairCom[52523:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4d06eb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key productWebView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00da8be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00efd5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00da8b21 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x000296cf _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x0002963d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x004a88d6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d1f2cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x004a72ed -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x004a9081 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x00361a94 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    10  UIKit                               0x0035f709 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    11  UIKit                               0x0035f5e3 -[UIViewController view] + 56
    12  UIKit                               0x00372230 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 120
    13  UIKit                               0x00370d86 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 64
    14  UIKit                               0x00372b7e -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 263
    15  UIKit                               0x003729ed -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 352
    16  UIKit                               0x002b1a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    17  UIKit                               0x004af1f2 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 422
    18  UIKit                               0x002b1a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    19  UIKit                               0x003401b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    20  UIKit                               0x00342647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    21  UIKit                               0x0034016c -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 49
    22  UIKit                               0x002b1a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    23  UIKit                               0x003401b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    24  UIKit                               0x00342647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    25  UIKit                               0x003411f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    26  UIKit                               0x002d60d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    27  UIKit                               0x002b737a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    28  UIKit                               0x002bc732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x016dea36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00d8a064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00cea6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00ce7983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00ce7240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00ce7161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x016dd268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x016dd32d GSEventRun + 115
    37  UIKit                               0x002c042e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    38  FairCom                             0x00001be0 main + 102
    39  FairCom                             0x00001b71 start + 53
    40  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're loading a nib. In that nib, you have an outlet named `productWebView` that's hooked up, presumably to a web view. The exception you're seeing is telling you that the outlet `productWebView` doesn't actually exist. Here's where it gets weird. The error says the object `<UIViewController 0x4d06eb0>` is the one that has this missing outlet. The weird bit is where it says `UIViewController` instead of the name of an actual view controller subclass. It sounds like you have a nib where the File's Owner is set up as one of your view controller subclasses, but at runtime you're actually just using an instance of `UIViewController` directly. You should verify that all the view controllers representing tabs in your tab bar controller are actual correct subclasses of `UIViewController` instead of just an instance of `UIViewController` itself.

Comment: Thank you! I went back and looked at my UITabBarItems and they weren't set to any specific nib/class, so it's a wonder why they worked at all!