# Updated to new XCode AFTER completing app, Apple rejects due to 5.0.1 crashes

Tags: ios, xcode

Like it says, I updated XCode basically at the end of my project. It still runs fine for me in iOS 5 and no error but Apple has rejected the app (twice) stating it crashes upon launch. Is there some change in updating that I could be overlooking? I have no idea why I can't recreate the error. Here is what they sent me.

The main screen is only an image view and a segmented control that I use as a couple of buttons... Not much there that could throw the error, please advise? :P

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x33ed18bf 0x352ec1e5 0x33ed15f5 0x328bb333 0x328bae33 0x32894f19 0x33e30803 0x33e31491 0x326354bf
>   0x32636bb9 0x3256fa45 0x323f9227 0x323f3313 0x323c1921 0x323c13bf
>   0x323c0d2d 0x30713df3 0x33ea5553 0x33ea54f5 0x33ea4343 0x33e274dd
>   0x33e273a5 0x323f2457 0x323ef743 0x2f79 0x2f44)
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: (0x33ed18bf 0x352ec1e5 0x33ed15f5 0x328bb333
>   0x328bae33 0x32894f19 0x33e30803 0x33e31491 0x326354bf 0x32636bb9
>   0x3256fa45 0x323f9227 0x323f3313 0x323c1921 0x323c13bf 0x323c0d2d
>   0x30713df3 0x33ea5553 0x33ea54f5 0x33ea4343 0x33e274dd 0x33e273a5
>   0x323f2457 0x323ef743 0x2f79 0x2f44)

Comment: Make sure you do an entire clean and then rebuild your project (maybe even manually remove the build folder from your project) - you should see the same error Apple sees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a connection in the IB Builder that is no longer defined as an IBOutlet in one of the header files.

Comment: If it doesn't load would it have to be on the first xib that loads or could it be on any of them? I can't find a connection that is missing declaration in a header.

Comment: @user1165647 I believe it could be any but I am not sure. It could also be something else unfortunately, as the stacktrace is not very helpful, but that is the most common cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem in nib/xib file. Please check all the connection to your outlet. Check this link (might be helpful): [UIWebView throwing NSUnknownKeyException iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847369/uiwebview-throwing-nsunknownkeyexception-ipad)

Comment: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
This is where the error is being shown to be does anyone know why iOS 5.0 would have issue but other version do not?